# Predicted values for new data using restricted cubic splines

Tags: r, lm, rms

I have some data that I'm modeling using restricted cubic splines. I'm using the `rcs` transformation function in the `rms` package to generate the transformed variables for a linear model. Here is an example using 5 knots.

```
library('rms')

my_df <- data.frame(
    y = -4 * -100:100 + -1.5 * (-100:100)**2 + 3 * (-100:100)**3 + rnorm(201, 0, 1e5),
    x = -100:100
)

mod <- lm(y ~ rcs(x, 5), data = my_df)
```

After I fit the data, I'd like to find the predicted `y` values for a specific domain of `x` values. Here is what I'm doing now:

```
new_data <- data.frame(x = -3:3)

predict(mod, newdata = new_data)
```

However, this generates a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In rcspline.eval(x, nk = nknots, inclx = TRUE, pc = pc, fractied = fractied) :
    5 knots requested with 7 unique values of x.  knots set to 5 interior values.
```

What does this mean, and what is going on? I expected that the knot locations should already be defined in `mod`, so I don't understand why it seems to be trying to find new knots for the seven `x` values that I give it. I can avoid the warning message by providing more `x` values in `new_data`, and just ignoring the ones I don't need, but I am concerned about what `predict` is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Hadley's comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633262/rcs-generates-bad-prediction-in-lm-models) you shouldn't expect `lm` to work with `rcs`. A quick demonstration why there's a problem:

```
mod <- lm(y ~ rcs(x, 5), data = my_df)

new_data <- data.frame(x = -3:3)
new_data2 <- data.frame(x = -300:300/100)

plot(new_data2$x, predict(mod, newdata = new_data2), type='l')
lines(new_data$x,predict(mod, newdata = new_data), col='red')
```

[image: Graph produced as code output]

The predictions vary depending on the number of x-values, even for the same range, so definitely not a good idea to combine these functions.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `predict` function will look in the formula and replace the variables it finds there with the ones in the `newdata`. The trick is, the `rcs` function determines where the knots are based on the provided data (distribution of it). So if the data in `new_data` has a different distribution than data in `my_df`, the knots are going to be at different locations and it will change the curve. Anyway, fixating the knot locations fixes the problem.

To fixate the knot locations, you cant't use the `rcs` function, but the `rcspline.eval` function, that takes knot locations as an argument. You can use the same function to calculate where the knots "should" be. See code below.

```
Knots <- rcspline.eval(my_df$x, knots.only = TRUE) # returns only locations of knots
# see ??Hmisc::rcspline.eval for details of how it determines knot locations
mod2 <- lm(y ~ rcspline.eval(x, knots = Knots), data = my_df) # fit model
predict(mod2, newdata = new_data) # predict based on mod2 and new data
```

Since the `mod2` formula contains the knot locations, the curve should be the same shape.